# warning #1011: missing return statement at end of non-void function

Tags: c++

I am getting this warning and it is repeating throughout the build .
Warning is from below code logic :Line number 6

```
class sample
{
private:                                                               //1
    // Private so that it can not be called                            //2
    sample();                                                          //3
    sample(sample const&);                                             //4
    // Assigning copy constructor with default constructor             //5
    sample& operator= (sample const&){};                               //6
    //                                                                 //7
    static sample *m_Instancesample;                                   //8
    static bool m_binstanceFlagsample;                                 //9
public:                                                                //10
    static sample *getInstance();                                      //11
    ~sample();                                                         //12
    void dummy(); 
};
```

Comment: remove `{}` at the end of the declaration.

Comment: Your comment for the assignment operator (which is not a constructor) makes very little sense.

Comment: Its a singleton class and I don't want that operator= should be overloaded .So I put this function as empty function

Comment: What's confusing about the error message? The function can't be "an empty function" because it has a non-`void` return type. You can omit the definition though since you'll never call it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `sample& operator= (sample const&){};` has defined a return type but you dont return anything. Either implement the function or remove the `{}`

Answer (score 1):

```
sample& operator= (sample const&){};  
                                 ^^
```

The `{}` part defines the function with empty body — the definition is missing return-statement.

Either define the function *properly* OR remove `{}` (i.e declare the function and define it elsewhere).

Comment: I removed the {} and run this code on my system and its running without above warning ..But I am thinking about some other platform if I will run it will give this warning once again

Comment: @NilaySrivastava: If you remove `{}`, then your code is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced like below:

```
  sample& operator= (sample const&){};
```

With:

```
  const sample& operator= (sample const& sampleInstance)
    {
        //Get the instance of your sample class as it is singleton you will get the same instance 
        return *sample::getInstance();
    };
```

Comment: Why? You were instructed to leave out the `{}`. Now you have several lines of code that can never be invoked. Utterly pointless.